# How to split an array by every nth appearance of a string?

Tags: php, string, explode

This question is different to [Split, a string, at every nth position, with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686561/split-a-string-at-every-nth-position-with-php), in that I want to split a string like the following:

```
foo|foo|foo|foo|foo|foo
```

Into this (every 2nd `|`):

```
array (3) {
  0 => 'foo|foo',
  1 => 'foo|foo',
  2 => 'foo|foo'
}
```

So, basically, I want a function similar to `explode()` (I really doubt that what I'm asking will be built-in), but which 'explodes' at every nth appearance of a certain string.

How is this possible?

Comment: Why completely change your question via an edit rather than asking a new one?

Comment: @JonLin I've ran out of space to ask questions, and I'm urgent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `explode + array_chunk + array_map + implode`

```
$string = "foo|foo|foo|foo|foo|foo";
$array = stringSplit($string,"|",2);
var_dump($array);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'foo|foo' (length=7)
  1 => string 'foo|foo' (length=7)
  2 => string 'foo|foo' (length=7)
```

Function used

```
function stringSplit($string, $search, $chunck) {
    return array_map(function($var)use($search){return implode($search, $var); },array_chunk(explode($search, $string),$chunck));
}
```

Comment: could you put that in a function please?